# using devise+omniauth access_token to pull from Google Sheets

Tags: devise, google-drive-api, ruby-on-rails-5, omniauth, google-sheets-api

I'd like to pull data from the Google Sheets spreadsheet of a logged-in user for some processing. I've set up an app  in the [Google Console](https://console.developers.com) with:

- Google Drive API
- Contacts API
- Google+ API
- Google Sheets API

I've also hooked up [devise/oauth](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2) so that it can successfully log in. However, whenever I try to use the `access_token` received in my `from_omniauth` method, I get:

```
dailyLimitExceededUnreg: Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.
```

What am I doing wrong?

My code (using the `google-api-client`) is as follows:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
require 'google/apis/drive_v2'

class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:google_oauth2]
  has_many :datasets, inverse_of: :user

  # Omniauth support
  def self.from_omniauth(access_token)
    #session = GoogleDrive::Session.new( access_token )
    drive = Google::Apis::DriveV2::DriveService.new
    files = drive.list_files(
      fields: "nextPageToken, files(id, name)",
      q: "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet' AND trashed != true",
    )


    data = access_token.info
    user = User.where(email: data['email']).first

    unless user
      user = User.create(
        email: data['email'],
        password: Devise.friendly_token[0, 20]
      )
    end
    user
  end
end
```

For the record, I also tried using the `google-drive` gem and met with the same response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While @pinyyid didn't have the complete answer in itself, it confirmed that I'd not been passing the credentials correctly (I'd tried previously, but not got it right). Ultimately, the following changes were necessary to make it work using the `google-drive` gem:

```
config.omniauth :google_oauth2, '<CLIENT_ID>', '<SECRET_KEY', scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive,https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'
```

The key here was to add the scopes I needed to the devise request.

Then, in my user object, I used the following:

```
def self.from_omniauth(access_token)
   session = GoogleDrive::Session.from_access_token(access_token[:credentials][:token])
   x = session.spreadsheet_by_title '<a spreadsheet title>' #or any call, really
```

I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

That error message means that your request to Drive is missing an `Authorization:` http header. This would normally look like `Authorization: bearer xxxxxxxxx` where xxxxx is the access token.

I can't see anywhere in your code where you set the access token into the `drive` object (but NB I don't know Ruby).